# Adding an explanation before Genitivattribut

Tags: genitive, apposition

I would like to know, that if one could add an explanation just before an Genitivattribut, if yes, how could it be achieved? Does my following attempt cause any misunderstandings?

> Was ist die oben genannten Phase von - eine sehr bekannte Kreativitätsmethode - "Brainstorming"?

Edit: Actually I would like to add some extra information in my example that was "Brainstorming ist eine sehr bekannte Kreativitätsmethode"
I've tried to translate my sentence to English, so that you can understand, what I try to convey.

> What is the above-mentioned phase of "Brainstorming", which is a well-known creative method?

or

> What is the above-mentioned phase of being a well-known creative method "Brainstorming"?

This could be with relative clause achieved but I would like to build a one line sentence with it.

And additionally, I've split my sentence into two parts, to make it clear

> Was ist die oben genannten Phase von Brainstorming, Brainstorming ist eine sehr bekannte Kreativitätsmethode.

Comment: Note that there is no genitive in sight here.

Comment: @chirlu "Die Phase von Brainstorming" is not a genitive?

Comment: Often, "von+<dat.>" is used as a poor man's genitive: "Das Auto von meinem Nachbarn". You can only beat that with "<dat.>+sein": "Meinem Nachbarn sein Auto" — please don't!

Answer (score 7):

"Von" takes the dative, though it's sometimes substituted for the genetive. The natural way to add an extra attributive clause is after the expression in question, and separated by commas, with the same case as the expression.

For your example, with a real genitive:

> Was ist die oben genannte Phase des "Brainstorming", einer sehr bekannten Kreativitätsmethode?

An alternative way is to use parenthesis:

> Was ist die oben genannte Phase des "Brainstorming" (einer sehr bekannten Kreativitätsmethode)?

In this case, you can even insert it as an extra genitive attribute, so you have a chain of two genitive attributes:

> Was ist die oben genannte Phase der sehr bekannten Kreativitätsmethode des Brainstormings?

This works because the expression "Methode des X" works.

The sentence looks still a bit odd, though, but we need context to phrase it more naturally. For starters, "die oben genannte" clashes with the use of the indefinite article and the presence of an additional explanation - if the text already mentioned brainstorming, it should have already talked about what brainstorming is, so it shouldn't be necessary to add this extra information in a question.

Comment: so is this usage wrong "die Phase von Brainstorming"?

Comment: And by the way could "oben genannten" be replaced with "oben erwähnte" ?

Comment: @Bergmann: It makes no difference if you use "oben genannte" or "oben erwähnte". "Die Phase von Brainstorming" is wrong, "die Phase des Brainstorming" is possible, "die Brainstorming-Phase" would be even more natural, depending on the context. If this was not a question about grammar, but if you want to know how to write this phrase, please give more context (that means the text "oben erwähnte" refers to) if you want better suggestions. (It's *always* a good idea to give as much context as possible for these kind of questions).